# Hiding row based on count of a group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report with Year (which is a group) and then some other fields and totals (there are other groups that aren't relevant).  I have a Grand Total Row at the bottom.  I want to only show that row if there is more than 1 year in the report (otherwise it just duplicates the Year footer).

I am not sure what I can use to do this. I tried CountDistinct, but that is not in scope. Is there a way to get a count of the group sections (like Group("Year").SectionCount) or something?

I am using SSRS 2005.

Comment: can you do a subreport per year?

Comment: can't you just do Count(Fields!Year.Value) < 1 ? Or, if in a different scope: Count(Fields!Year.Value, "YourDatasetName") < 1

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674071/group-and-subtotal-columns-in-reporting-services-2005

Comment: Ok, now I saw that Year is a group, what field/expression you use to group? You should post that so we can help you.

Comment: I tried =CountDistinct(Fields!YEAR_OPENED.Value, "DS_SLA") = 1 and that works. Thanks

Comment: The group is just a field called Year_Opened

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question (note that you can edit it to add details). Tell us about a sample dataset and report layout to reproduce the problem, tell us what specific things you've tried and why they didn't work, etc. To us it seems like it's a trivial problem to solve, but that's probably because we're missing some context.